# How to show that the sum of the following i.i.d. tends to infinity?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I have i.i.d $\{\zeta_{n}\}$ defined as follow:

$$\{\zeta_{n}=\int_{\sigma_{n}}^{\tau_{n}}1_{(0,\infty)}(X(s))ds\}$$

where $X(s)$ is a one dimensional Brownian Motion and $\sigma_{1}=\min\{t:X(t)=0\}$, $\tau_{1}=\min\{t>\sigma_{1}:X(t)=-1\}$, $\sigma_{2}=\min\{t>\tau_{1}:X(t)=0\}$,$\tau_{2}=\min\{t>\sigma_{2}:X(t)=-1\}\cdots $ etc.

How to show that $\sum_{n} \zeta_{n}$ converges to infinity a.s.? I think to use strong law of large number, but I do not get satisfactory proof myself.

Comment: Are those really *identical* distributions? Even if so, you're making the problem unnecessarily complicated by presenting each one differently.

Comment: Anyways, a simple sketch would be to compute the probability that the sum does not converge to infinity, which will be no more than the probability that only finitely many terms are less than some chosen constant.

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, they are independent and identical distribution. Indeed, I want to use strong law of large number to conclude it, but that theorem states $\sum_{n}\zeta_{n}/n$ converges to $\mu$ almost surely, but what I want to have $\sum_{n}\zeta_{n}$ converges to infinity.

Comment: The law of large numbers for i.i.d. integrable random variables shows that $\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\zeta_k\to E(\zeta)>0$ almost surely. Choose $0<c<E(\zeta)$, then $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\zeta_k\geqslant c\,n$ for every $n$ large enough, which is more than enough to conclude that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\zeta_k\to+\infty$ almost surely.